# How to open multiple dialog box in angular4

Tags: angular, dialog

I am working on an angular4 project where I need to open dialog boxes one after another. I am using the material to integrate dialog boxes. Right now single dialog box is working well but I want to second dialog box while the first one is still open and if I close the second one I should see first one.

I have done dialog box using this article:- https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/making-use-of-dialogs-in-material-2-mddialog-7533d27df41

Is there any guideline or method to do this. Any help is appreciable.

**app.component.html:-**

```
<button (click)="dialogBox()"> Open first dialog box </button>
```

**app.component.ts:-**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { PopupService } from './Popup.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'app',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

   popupResponse:any;
   constructor( private popupService : PopupService)
   {}

   ngOnInit() {}

   public dialogBox()
   {
      this.popupService.dialog().
         subscribe(res => {this.popupResponse = res},
                   err => console.log(err),
                   ()  => console.log(this.popupResponse)
                  );
   } 
}
```

**Popup.service.ts:-**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { MdDialogRef, MdDialog, MdDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { PopupComponent } from './popup.component';

@Injectable()
export class PopupService {

   constructor(private http: Http, private dialog: MdDialog) { }

   dialog()
   {
      let dialogOpen: MdDialogRef<PopupComponent>;
      dialogOpen = this.dialog.open(PopupComponent);

      return dialogOpen.afterClosed();
   }
}
```

**popup.component.ts:-**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'popup',
  templateUrl: './popup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popup.component.scss']
})
export class PopupComponent implements OnInit {
   constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<TeamMembersPopupComponent>)
   {}

   ngOnInit() {}

   secondDialogBox() {

   }
}
```

**popup.component.html:-**

```
<div>
   <div>
      <span class="material-icons" (click)="dialogRef.close()">clear</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <h2> Popup </h2>
      <button (click)="secondDialogBox()"> Second dialog box </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

How to open second dialog box but first dialog box is not close.

Comment: i just tried their plunker, if you move the open dialog box 2 inside your first dialog box body, its working.... or I'm missing something?

Comment: Please share a code.

Answer (score 0):

i just tried their plunker, if you move the open dialog box 2 inside your first dialog box body, its working.... or I'm missing something

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>{{bodyText}}</p>
    <button (click)="openModal('custom-modal-1')">Open Modal 1</button>

</div>

<modal id="custom-modal-1">
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h1>A Custom Modal!</h1>
            <p>
                Home page text: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="bodyText" />
            </p>
            <button (click)="openModal('custom-modal-2')">Open Modal 2</button>
            <button (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-1');">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
</modal>

<modal id="custom-modal-2">
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-body" style="height:80px; background-color: red;">
            <h1>A Tall Custom Modal!</h1>
            <button (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-2');">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-background"></div>
</modal>
```

Comment: In your code:- Open first dialog box and if open second dialog box, the first dialog box is closed. But this is not my requirement.

Comment: well if you open second dialog box, first is not closed, its hidden behind the second dialog.... whats your requirement?

Comment: My requirement is:- First dialog box is open and in first dialog box create a button, click on this button show second dialog box but the first dialog is not close.

Comment: thats exactly whats happening, OK i have changed the background color and height just to prove that the first dialog box is not closed when you open the second one

Comment: You are done this dialog using modal. But I am trying this using this reference:- https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Comment: i just used the plunker you have given in your question... anyways hope you find solution soon!

Comment: Hi, I have used two service for multiple popup, It will be work fine on chrome, firebox. But not working on safari.